# How to integrate current signal to be able to measure it with 50 ohm input impedance of ADC

Tags: current-source, input-impedance, integrator

## Preliminaries

I am using a photomultiplier tube (PMT) in order to amplify scintillator's light signals. Some of the studied scintillators have long decay time and poor light yield. That makes these signals difficult to use as a trigger on an oscilloscope/ADC (because of the noise that has similar amplitude). This is how they look like on 50 Ohm load of the oscilloscope:
[image]
In case of the oscilloscope as a measuring tool I solved this problem using the RC-integrator. NOTE: PMT is a current source:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flDBKB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This gives me time constant about 800ns which is enough to discriminate signal pulse shapes. This is how they look like on 1MOhm load of the oscilloscope:
[image]

## Requirements

I need to be able to preserve information about the scintillation curve. E.g. using the above-mentioned RC-integrator I know the response function:

[image]

So making an assumption about the exact form of [image] I can restore its parameters later.

## Problem

However, I cannot use the same approach with ADC as a measuring tool because unlike the oscilloscope it doesn't provide an ability to change the input impedance. Its input impedance is 50 Ohm. For example, adding a resistor in series with the input of ADC obviously doesn't fit because of a voltage division. What should I do in this case? I thought if I could change the input impedance effectively and then use the previous solution.

## EDIT (The device list)

- PMT : Hamamatsu R1847S @ 1500V
- Oscilloscope : OWON TDS8204, Z_in either 50 Ohm or 1M Ohm
- ADC : CAEN N6720A, Z_in = 50 Ohm

Answer (score 1):

You would use a [non inverting op amp buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_amplifier) between the RC integrator and the ADC.

That gives you the high impedance you need to connect to the integrator and the low impedance you need to connect to the ADC.

A (drastically simplified) example from the Wikipedia page looks like this:

[image]

The triangle shaped thing is the schematic representation of an operational amplifier.

The devil is, of course, in the details.

All opamps are not created equal:

- Some have limited bandwidth.
- Some have limited input voltage ranges.
- Some are not stable when used as a buffer.
- Some can drive low impedance loads better than others.
- There are **many** more properties of opamps than I've listed here.

Building a completed buffer around an opamp and meeting particular requirements of bandwidth, noise rejection, voltage input range, etc. can be challenging.

If your ADC is a circuit you have built yourself, then you may want to learn about opamps and build your own buffer.

If you are using a commercial ADC module (data acquisition system of some kind) then you will probably want to consider using a commercially made buffer module.  Find one that meets your needs for bandwidth, voltage range, noise, what-ever-else, then pay your bucks and get on with your measurements.

You might also look into ADC modules with high impedance input.  It might be cheaper to use an appropriate module to start with rather than trying to continue with a piece of equipment that doesn't do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other solution, but have a further suggestion: increase the bias voltage on your photomultiplier so that the gain is higher. It it reasonable to have a peak amplitude of 100s of millivolts per photon on a photomultiplier tube into 50ohms. This is easily enough to directly trigger or sample using a typical ADC.

Comment: The problem to use this approach would be a) High gain of PMT results in decreasing the signal to noise ratio and b) Signal from the single thermal electron from the photocathode increases also provided the supply voltage increased. So I wouldn't solve the problem with triggering.

Comment: BTW, I already use the working voltage of the PMT. I edited the question.

Comment: PMTs actually have a very wide range of bias voltages where the dark counts are newrly independent of gain. Are you sure you're at the optimal operating point? If not, SNR can be dramatically increased just by increasing the voltage.

Comment: Agreed, but this is not the essential. The crucial is that the scintillator's photons generate a few photoelectrons in a very long time. Therefore, these signals are individual photoelectrons and you cannot set the threshold of ADC in order to trigger ONLY them because you would also trigger the single photoelectrons from thermal emission. And I don't see how the increased gain resolves that.